# java struts spring from Java 6 to 8 / namespace class must not be null

Tags: java, spring, struts, javabeans, upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade a Java web application from Java 6 and Java 8.

It's a 5 layers application, I have corrected all errors and  maven is building all without any errors.

I had no error on starting the app on tomcat 9, when I tried to access to the login page, I got the following error :

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [/crm] threw exception [Unable to instantiate Action, com.xxx.coordination.EnterAction,  defined for 'enter' in namespace '/'Class must not be null - action - file:/C:/git/yyy/crm-webapp/WebContent/WEB-INF/classes/home.xml:7:89] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class must not be null
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:113)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.isSimpleProperty(BeanUtils.java:360)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.unsatisfiedNonSimpleProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:846)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireByName(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:756)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:715)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:267)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.spring.SpringObjectFactory.autoWireBean(SpringObjectFactory.java:167)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.spring.SpringObjectFactory.buildBean(SpringObjectFactory.java:154)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.spring.SpringObjectFactory.buildBean(SpringObjectFactory.java:128)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:141)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildAction(ObjectFactory.java:111)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.createAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:270)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.init(DefaultActionInvocation.java:360)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.access$000(DefaultActionInvocation.java:38)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$1.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:78)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.<init>(DefaultActionInvocation.java:70)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.<init>(DefaultActionInvocation.java:66)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.prepare(DefaultActionProxy.java:189)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(StrutsActionProxyFactory.java:41)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:494)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:418)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.xxx.init.MobileFilter.doFilter(MobileFilter.java:38)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.xxx.coordination.SuiviAcces.doFilter(SuiviAcces.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:412)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1385)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I'm using struts 2.1, the configuration file is simple and seems to be still the same in the newer version.

```
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.1//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.1.dtd">

<struts>
    <package name="home" namespace="/" extends="default">
        <action name="enter" class="com.xxx.coordination.EnterAction">
            <result>/jsp/loginV2.jsp</result>
        </action>

    </package>
</struts>
```

Here is the class

```
package com.xxx.coordination;

public class EnterAction extends CRMAction {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7783257066320013576L;

    @Override
    public String execute() {

        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

I found that I had to add the following line in the applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="enterBean" class="com.xxx.coordination.EnterAction"></bean>
```

and had to change also in struts to

```
<action name="enter" class="enterBean">
```

So my question, why was it working on Java 6 and have to change it now on Java 8

Comment: `<action name="enter" class="com.xxx.coordination.EnterAction">`. it says `xxx`. should it be `abw`? It don't know Struts but `class=enterBean` should reference a class and not a bean. am I right? Just some suggestions.

Comment: ah mistook in the post, I changed to <bean id="enterBean" class="com.xxx.coordination.EnterAction"></bean>

Comment: it seems that the spring version 2.0.1 is not working well on a tomcat JRE 1.8